# Amazon API Gateway HTTP Proxy で Query String Paramerer に静的な値を付加

Tags: aws, aws-api-gateway

Amazon API Gatewayにて
`/api/?hoge=fuga` の様なリクエストを
`https://endpoint/?hoge=fuga&foo=bar` の様にして、外部APIエンドポイントに中継する際に追加のQuery String Parameterを付加して送信したいのですがどうしたらよいでしょうか？
この追加のパラメータは毎回同じものを追加したいです。調べてもAPI Gateway単体ではQueryStringに静的な値をマッピングする方法が見つからず困っています。

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway 単体ではリクエスト内容を変更する事はできないと思います。

Lambdaにリクエストを渡し、Lambdaでパラメータを付加して外部APIにリクエストを送るというのであれば実現できるとは思います。

Answer (score 0):

やってみたことがないので、あくまでも推測ですが。

統合リクエストの設定で統合タイプをhttpにし、マッピングテンプレートで追加のパラメータを記述できるように思います。あくまでも固定の値の場合でしょうけど。